# Why does log appear so frequently in algorithmic complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, asymptotic-complexity, computer-science-theory

This question is about whether there is some abstract similarity between the solutions that leads to the appearance of log in problems such as sorting and searching. Or, more simply, why does log appear so frequently in algorithmic complexity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logarithms often show up when a problem can be repeatedly reduced in size by a multiplicative factor. By definition there's a logarithmic number of steps required to reduce the problem to constant size (e.g. size 1).

A typical example would be repeatedly eliminating half of the dataset, as is done in binary search. This gives `O(log2(n))` complexity. Some sorting algorithms work by repeatedly splitting the dataset in half, and therefore also have a logarithmic term in their time complexity.

More generally, logarithms frequently show up in solutions to [divide-and-conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) recurrence relations. See [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) in Wikipedia for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**log** appears very often in computer science because of the **boolean** logic. Everything can be reduced to **true vs false** or **1 vs 0** or **to be or not to be**. If you have an `if` statement you have one option, otherwise you have the other option. This can be applied for bits (you have 0 or 1) or in high impact problems, but there is a decision. And as it is in the real life, when you take a decision, you don't care about the problems that could have happened if you had decided otherwise. This is why **log<sub>2</sub>(n)** appears very often.

Then, every situation that is more complicated ( E.g.: choose one possible state from 3 states ) can be reduced to **log<sub>2</sub>(n)** => the logarithm base doesn't matter (a constant doesn't influence trend for a function - it has the same degree ):

- Mathematical proof:

  ```
            loga(y)      1
  logx(y) = ------- = -------- * loga(y) = constant * loga(y)
            loga(x)    loga(x)
  ```
- Proof for programmers:

  ```
  switch(a) { 
      case 1: ... ;
      case 2: ... ;
      ...
      default: ... ;
  }
  ```

  is similar to:

  ```
  if (a == 1) {  
      ...
  } else {
      if ( a == 2 ) {
          ...
      }
      ...
  }
  ```

  ( a `switch` for `k` options is equivalent to `k-1` `if-else` statements, where `k` = constant )

**But why log** ? Because it is the inverse for an exponential. At the first decision you break the big problem into 2 parts. Then you break only the "good" half in 2 parts, etc.

```
n      = n/2^0         // step 1
n/2    = n/2^1         // step 2
n/4    = n/2^2         // step 3
n/8    = n/2^3         // step 4
...
n/2^i  = n/2^i         // step i+1
```

**Q**: How many steps are there ?

**A**: i+1 ( from 0 to i )

Because it stops when you find the wanted element (there are no other decisions you can take) => `n = 2^i`. If we apply the logarithm, base 2:

```
log2(n) = log2(2^i)
log2(n) = i
=> i + 1 = log2(n) + 1
```

But a constant doesn't influence the complexity => you have ~**log<sub>2</sub>(n) steps**.

Comment: This is an interesting argument. However, isn't it true that practically every algorithm uses `if` statements yet only a small fraction of algorithms have logs in their time complexity?

Comment: I didn't mentioned `if` as it is in programming languages. I mentioned `if` as a decision statement ( to be or not to be ). It can be seen even in the binary representation ( sometimes there is '1', sometimes there is '0' ) or it can be seen more generally as it is in a binary search, but it creates logical branches every time. I agree with you that not any `if` statement influences the global time complexity.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. I'm not yet clear on how it relates to the answer @NPE provided because it is totally independent of reducing the problem size. It seems to apply to all decision problems.

Answer (score 0):

log appears a lot in algorithm complexity especially in recursive algorithms..

lets take at a binary search for example.

you have a sorted array A of 100 elements and your looking for the number 15..

in a binary search you will look at the middle element (50) and compare it to 15.. if element is greater than 15 then you find the middle element between 50 and 100 which is 75.. and compare again.. if 15 is greater than the element at 75 then you look at the element between 75 and 100 which is element 87... you continue to do this until you find the element or until there is no more middle number...

each time you do this method of checking the middle number you cut the total number of elements remaining to search in half..

so the first pass will give you O(n/2) complexity.. the next pass will be O(n/4)... O(n/8) and so on..
to represent this pattern we use logs..

since we are cutting the number of elements to search in half with each pass of the algorithm that becomes the log base so the binary search will yield a O(log2(n)) complexity

most algorithms try to 'cut' the number of operations down to as few as possible by breaking the original data into separate parts to solve and that is why log shows up so often